# Returning an updated column value based on the conditions of another column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, self-join

I have a table `Referrals` with these columns:

- `ref_id`
- `referrer_id(same as profile id)`
- `referrer_bonus_amount`
- `referral_valid`
- `valid_from`
- `valid_till`.

I need to write code to extend the `valid_till` date for a month of tenants who have referred more than two times. The number of references made can calculated by the number of occurrences of a particular number (`profile_id`) in the column `referrer_id` (same as profile id). The below two pieces of code are doing their job individually but I don't know how to join them to get the desired result.

```
select DATEADD(mm, 1, valid_till)
from Referrals

select 
    [referrer_id(same as profile id)], 
    count([referrer_id(same as profile id)]) 
from referrals
group by [referrer_id(same as profile id)]
having count([referrer_id(same as profile id)]) > 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MM, 1, valid_till) 
FROM   referrals
WHERE  referrer_id IN (SELECT   referrer_id
                       FROM     referrals
                       GROUP BY referrer_id
                       HAVING   COUNT(*) > 2)
```

Or if you really need to update the table and not just query the added month, you could use the same idea in an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE referrals 
SET    valid_till = DATEADD(MM, 1, valid_till) 
WHERE  referrer_id IN (SELECT   referrer_id
                       FROM     referrals
                       GROUP BY referrer_id
                       HAVING   COUNT(*) > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using a `join`.  However, I'm not sure what the exact condition is that matches between the table:

```
select DATEADD(month, 1, valid_till)
from Referrals r join
     (select [referrer_id(same as profile id)], count([referrer_id(same as profile id)]) 
      from referrals
      group by [referrer_id(same as profile id)]
      having count([referrer_id(same as profile id)]) > 2
     ) rr
     on rr.ref_id = [referrer_id(same as profile id)];
```